# How to Compare two columns in two different csv's (old and new) and update a third column if a value exists in old csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two CSVs. The first one contains a list of all previous customers with IDs assigned to them. And a new csv in which I'm auto generating IDs with following code:

```
df['ID'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%m%d%y') + df.index.map(str)
```

OLD.csv

```
ID            FirstName   LastName
1             John        Smith
2             Jack        Ma
3             John        Wick
....          ....        ....
210906ABC3    Jon         Snow
210907ABC0    Peter       Parker
210907ABC1    Tony        Stark
```

NEW.csv with current script

```
ID            FirstName   LastName
210908ABC0    Black       Widow
210908ABC1    Steve       Rogers
210908ABC2    John        Wick
210908ABC3    John        Rambo
210908ABC4    Tony        Stark
```

I need to compare the FirstName, LastName columns from the CSVs and if the customer already exists in OLD.csv, instead of generating a new ID, it should take the ID value from OLD.csv

Expected output for NEW.csv

```
ID            FirstName   LastName
210908ABC1    Black       Widow
210908ABC2    Steve       Rogers
3             John        Wick
210908ABC3    John        Rambo
1             John        Smith
```

In the future I might need to compare three or four columns and only assign the IDs if all the columns match. FirstName and LastName and (CellPhone or Address) and (Location or SSN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have both files in two dataframes df1 and df2 you can merge the two then update the ID in the first file and print only the columns from the first file, this will only work for files up to a few thousand rows as the merge is quite slow

```
df2.columns = [x + "_2" for x in df2.columns]  # to avoid auto renaming by pd
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on = key_cols1, right_on = key_cols2)

# update the ID column
result.ID = np.where(result.ID_2.isnull(), result.ID, result.ID_2)

print(result.to_csv(index=False,columns=df1.columns))
```

Edit:
this is a simple working example, file1 (df1) is the file you want to update and file2 is the file that contains the IDs you want to copy over to file1

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, argparse, os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='update id in file1 with id from file2.')
parser.add_argument('-k', help='key column both file', required=True)
parser.add_argument('file1', help='file1 to be updated')
parser.add_argument('file2', help='file2 contains updates for file1')

args = parser.parse_args()
if not os.path.isfile(args.file1): raise ValueError('File does not exist: ' + args.file1)
if not os.path.isfile(args.file2): raise ValueError('File does not exist: ' + args.file2)

df1 = pd.read_csv(args.file1,dtype=str,header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(args.file2,dtype=str,header=0)
df2.columns = [x + "_2" for x in df2.columns]

key_col1 = [list(df1.columns)[int(x)] for x in args.k.split(",")]
key_col2 = [list(df2.columns)[int(x)] for x in args.k.split(",")]
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on = key_col1, right_on = key_col2)

result.ID = np.where(result.ID_2.isnull(), result.ID, result.ID_2)

print(result.to_csv(index=False,columns=df1.columns))
```

use as follows:

```
$ python merge.py -k 1,2 file1.csv file2.csv

ID,FirstName,LastName
210908ABC0,Black,Widow
210908ABC1,Steve,Rogers
3,John,Wick
210908ABC3,John,Rambo
210907ABC1,Tony,Stark
```

make sure that the key is unique per row otherwise you can get multiple joins generating extra rows in the output file.

Comment: To clarify, ID would contain the IDs of original file, which I intend to keep. ID_2 would contain IDs i've generated, which I intend to replace with the older ID.

I think this would work better for me. `result.ID_2 = np.where(result.ID_2.notnull(), result.ID, result.ID_2)`. 

I would need to copy these ID_2 values onto df2 for corresponding First and Last names replacing the ID2. Could you guide me with that?

Comment: @user3101  make sure the file you want to update is in df1 and the file containing the updates is in df2, see the example i added above

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot more sense, Thank you. 
Sorry, I didn't fully understand the parser arguments. Eliminated from the script until I can read up more on that.